# Замена значений в json

Tags: json, замена

Всем привет! Подскажите пожалуйста, вот файл json у одного из игроков (игра the isle), хочу в магазине добавить замену значений хп, стамины, голода, жажды, какой код мне нужно вписать, что бы заменились именно те значения которые указал, причем у каждого персонажа (динозавра) свое название, свое количество хп, как это можно сделать что бы работало на всех одинакого?

```
{
    "CharacterClass": "Camara",
    "DNA": "",
    "Location_Isle_V3": "X=-386967.969 Y=110613.703 Z=-72539.336",
    "Rotation_Isle_V3": "P=0.000000 Y=-19.344364 R=0.000000",
    "Growth": "1.0",
    "Hunger": "7500",
    "Thirst": "99",
    "Stamina": "350",
    "Health": "12000",
    "BleedingRate": "0",
    "Oxygen": "40",
    "bGender": false,
    "bIsResting": true,
    "bBrokenLegs": false,
    "ProgressionPoints": "0",
    "ProgressionTier": "1",
    "UnlockedCharacters": "",
    "CameraRotation_Isle_V3": "P=0.000000 Y=70.655731 R=0.000000",
    "CameraDistance_Isle_V3": "850.003845"
}
```

Comment: код-то на каком языке программирования? алгол? smalltalk?

Comment: Игра на движке UE4, вероятно С++